# How can I get rid of duplicates so I can change my table PK?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, duplicates

I have a table with several fields. The first 3 fields are the PK.

```
Field1 (PK)
Field2 (PK)
Field3 (PK)
Field4
Field5
Field6
```

Now I want to change the table structure to delete Field3 and make Field4 part of the PK instead. The problem is that Field4 is not currently unique so there can be more than 1 Field1 + Field2 + Field4 combination in the table. I want to delete any extras and keep just one Field1 + Field2 + Field4 combination.

This is the query that lets me know which Field1 + Field2 + Field4 combinations have duplicates:

```
select Field1, Field2, Field4
from myTable
group by Field1, Field2, Field4
having count(Field4)>1
```

But I can't figure out how to use this to delete the duplicates and leave just one single record (any will do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like that :

```
delete m from 
myTable m join
(
 select Field1, Field2, Field4, max(field3) field3
 from myTable
 group by Field1, Field2, Field4
 having count(Field4)>1
) m2
on m.field1 = m2.field1 and m.field2 = m2.field2 and m.field4 = m2.field4 and m.field3 <> m2.field3
```

This approach is based on the assumption that (Field1, Field2, Field3) is a primary key and hence each duplicate row (Field1, Field2, Field4) will have different Field3.

Comment: actually it worked well as a select (I got the correct records that need to be deleted) but when I try it as a delete I get a syntax error.... `Incorrect syntax near 'm'` and `Incorrect syntax near 'm2'`

Comment: just a syntax issue - looks like you need "delete m from..."

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of require to add an identity column in your table:

```
alter table mytable
add id int identity

delete from mytabtle a where 
exists (select * from mytable b where a.field1=b.field1 and a.field2=b.field2 and a.field4=b.field4 and b.id>a.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) window function you can do something like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Field1, 
           Field2, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Field4 ORDER BY Field1, Field2) As RN
    FROM MyTable
)

DELETE 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN > 1
```